# Vaadin router nested routes

Tags: vaadin, router, web-component, lit-element

My application is written in JS using LitElement. I want to have these routes in my application:

```
/auth/login
/auth/register
```

In my app.js I configured my router like this:

```
router.setRoutes([
        {
            path: '/auth',
            component: 'yp-auth-page',
            action: async () => await import('./modules/auth/yp-auth-page'),
        },
    ]);
```

Now in yp-auth-page I want to do something like this:

```
router.setRoutes([
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: 'yp-login-page',
        },
   ]);
```

But as soon as I call `router.setRoutes` in my child component (yp-auth-page.js), I get an error in App.js:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Vaadin.Router] Page not found (/auth)

I'm just starting to learn Vaadin router, and I couldn't find any posts about this error, and nested routing tutorial is using TS decorators so I couldn't find a way to nest routes like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add them below childern like that

```
import './modules/auth/yp-auth-page'
    router.setRoutes([
        {
            path: '/auth',
            component: 'yp-auth-page',
            children:[
                {
                   path: '/login',
                  component: 'yp-login-page',
                  action: () =>import('you login component')
               }
            ]
        },
    ]);
```

when you want use it just import Router from  @vaadin/router
and navigate  with `Router.go('/auth/login')`